SwiftUI Spline 3d model inside of ScrollView
I'm a beginner to Swift and SwiftUI and I am building a side-project. I am attempting to load an interactive 3d model (fetching from Spline Cloud link) into a ScrollView, but the gestures with the 3d model also interact with the ScrollView and make it impossible for the user to interact with the 3d model without interruption from the ScrollView.
I aim to have my interactable 3d model imported from Spline at the top of a Home page with the rest of the page containing relevant user stats. I looked into Exclusive Gestures and Simultaneous Gestures, but neither seemed to be the right answer.
Here is the link I used for documentation on importing the 3D Model: Spline Documentation
Here is my Home View:
import SwiftUI
import SplineRuntime

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // Header
            HStack {
                Text("Home")
                    .font(.title)
                    .bold()
                    .padding([.leading, .top])
                Spacer()
            }
            
            // 3D Model
            SplineModel()
        }
    }
}

struct SplineModel: View {
    var body: some View {

        // fetching from cloud
        let link = URL(string: "https://build.spline.design/G6QJHoNN2abqhaMbBmGM/scene.splineswift")!

        SplineView(sceneFileURL: link).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(height: 300)
            .background(Color.gray)
    }
}

#Preview {
    HomeView()
}

Is this possible to achieve with the current Swift 5 API?

Try highPriorityGesture().

This seems to work when you have two gestures being recognized in the same view. I want to disable the scrolling on the ScrollView when I am interacting with the 3D model, which is to say I want my gestures on the 3D model to essentially block gestures on the ScrollView. I'm not sure if that's the way I should be thinking about it... but hopefully that makes sense.
